# How i test OAuth2 resource server with mock

Tags: spring-boot, testing, oauth-2.0, mocking

I have my OAUTH2 server, which other services need to request a jwt token to be able to access the endpoints.

So far so good, everything is going well.

But now I'm writing the tests, and they all return error 401 without authorization. I already understood that it is because the tests do not make any requests for the OAuth2 server.

What I wanted to know is how do I do a Mock from a JWT or from the oauth2 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both tips but without success.

My resource server config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ServidorDeRecursos extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ConfiguracaoDeToken configuracaoDeToken;

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(configuracaoDeToken.tokenServices());
    }
}
```

My token config

```
@Configuration
public class ConfiguracaoDeToken {

    @Autowired
    private ConversorDeTokenDeAcessoPersonalizado conversorDeTokenDeAcessoPersonalizado;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(conversorDeTokenDeAcessoPersonalizado);

        final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }
}

@Component
public class ConversorDeTokenDeAcessoPersonalizado extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> claims) {
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(claims);
        authentication.setDetails(claims);
        return authentication;
    }
}

@Component
public class TokenPayload {

    private Map<String, Object> getExtraInfo() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauthDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        var details = (Map<String, Object>) oauthDetails.getDecodedDetails();
        return details;
    }

    public String payloadLogin() {
        return getExtraInfo().get("user_name").toString();
    }

    public Long payloadIdEmpresa() {
        return Long.parseLong(getExtraInfo().get("idEmpresa").toString());
    }

    public Long payloadIdFuncionario() {
        return Long.parseLong(getExtraInfo().get("idFuncionario").toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to mock a JWT token directly, you can use a different signing key for your tests so you are not creating a security break for your backend.

Comment: How do I do this? Do you have an example?

Comment: you can create your own JWT token using a framework, there are plenty of them on jwt.io

Answer (score 1):

If you need to mock a JWT, best solution is to use a JWT generator targeting your tests using **[Nimbus JWT + JOSE library](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt)**

For example, below is a code directly extracted from [**JSON Web Token (JWT) with RSA signature**](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-rsa-signature), which shows JWT generation as well as assertion which is very much similar to a test.

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.nimbusds.jose.*;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.*;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.*;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.gen.*;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.*;


// RSA signatures require a public and private RSA key pair, the public key 
// must be made known to the JWS recipient in order to verify the signatures
RSAKey rsaJWK = new RSAKeyGenerator(2048)
    .keyID("123")
    .generate();
RSAKey rsaPublicJWK = rsaJWK.toPublicJWK();

// Create RSA-signer with the private key
JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(rsaJWK);

// Prepare JWT with claims set
JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
    .subject("alice")
    .issuer("https://c2id.com")
    .expirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000))
    .build();

SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(
    new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256).keyID(rsaJWK.getKeyID()).build(),
    claimsSet);

// Compute the RSA signature
signedJWT.sign(signer);

// To serialize to compact form, produces something like
// eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.SW4gUlNBIHdlIHRydXN0IQ.IRMQENi4nJyp4er2L
// mZq3ivwoAjqa1uUkSBKFIX7ATndFF5ivnt-m8uApHO4kfIFOrW7w2Ezmlg3Qd
// maXlS9DhN0nUk_hGI3amEjkKd0BWYCB8vfUbUv0XGjQip78AI4z1PrFRNidm7
// -jPDm5Iq0SZnjKjCNS5Q15fokXZc8u0A
String s = signedJWT.serialize();

// On the consumer side, parse the JWS and verify its RSA signature
signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(s);

JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(rsaPublicJWK);
assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));

// Retrieve / verify the JWT claims according to the app requirements
assertEquals("alice", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
assertEquals("https://c2id.com", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer());
assertTrue(new Date().before(signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()));
```

What I would do is extract similar JWT generation functionality to a dedicated class. Add few constructor parameters (or use a builder pattern) to that and use it for all my mock returns. That way you can test for correct , incorrect as well as unexpected scenarios.